# Ajax.BeginForm second httppost request fail in mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have ajax form in partial cshtml and use Html.RenderPartial to render the partial view in MVC. The Ajax.Beginform works successfully on the first submit, but fail on the subsequent submit.

The error shown by the browser console is 500 Internal Server Error. When debugging, the postback action does not jump into any of the controller action. I assume the postback link is correct since the source code of before submit and after submit looks the same to me.

Comment: it seems like there is problem with antiforgerytoken when using ajax

Comment: 500 error means there is error in your server side code.Check error when you submit again.